# What is the equivalent of an Objective-C id in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use an @IBAction to tie up a button click event to a Swift method. In Objective-C the parameter type of the IBAction is id. What is the equivalent of id in Swift?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## Swift 3

`Any`, if you know the sender is never `nil`.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : Any) {
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

`Any?`, if the sender could be `nil`.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : Any?) {
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

## Swift 2

`AnyObject`, if you know the sender is never `nil`.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

`AnyObject?`, if the sender could be `nil`.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : AnyObject?) {
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
}
```

Comment: Or sometimes `AnyObject?`, depending on how you want to handle nil.

Comment: From docs:Swift includes a protocol type named AnyObject that represents any kind of object, just as id does in Objective-C. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: Or if you are sure it is the button just UIButton instead of anyObject

Comment: AnyObject? if you think that nil might be called (quite often people call IBAction functions from code, without a sender), MyClass or MyClass? if you know that the sender is of no other class than MyClass.

Comment: As of Swift 3, Objective-C interfaces that use `id` and untyped collections will be imported into Swift as taking the `Any` type instead of `AnyObject`. [SE-0116](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md)

Answer (score 0):

AnyObject

Other mapping type,

> Remap certain Objective-C core types to their alternatives in Swift,
>   like NSString to String
>
> Remap certain Objective-C concepts to matching concepts in Swift, like
>   pointers to optionals